# Binding a second instance of a form to a second instance of a data module?

Tags: delphi, data-binding, delphi-2010

I have a Form which has data aware controls bound to datasets in a datamodule. I need to create additional instances of both the form and datamodule in the same application.

I deleted the global variable that was automatically created when the data module was first added to the project. To my delight, controls in the designer could still be bound to datasets in the data module without this global variable. I'm assuming the IDE is parsing the dfm of the datamodule so the designer can still "see" the datamodule. (without the data module loaded in the IDE the list of data sources is empty)

When I create two instances of the form and two instances of the datamodule at runtime both instances of the form appear to be bound to only the first data module that was created. Inspecting the second instance of the data module reveals that the `Name` property has a number suffix that wasn't there at design time.

The form depends on a lot of datasets in the data module. Is there an easier way to bind the second form instance to the second data module's datasets without resorting to hand coded `SomeControl.DataSource := Module2.dsSomeData` for every single control?

I'm open to alternative suggestions as well. One solution would be to move the datasets to the form itself. Still it seems a shame if design time data binding only works on singletons.

Comment: Anything that isn't explicitly setup at design time must be setup at run time. That global variable is used when the datamodule is auto created (see auto-create forms in project settings or take a look at .DPR). If you delete it and you're auto-creating it, it won't compile. Either pass the form to a method in the data module or pass the data module to a method on the form and hook everything up there.

Comment: Neither form nor datamodule are autocreated so the global var isn't the issue. From the answer Mark posted below it seems the issue is with the component streaming system.

Comment: If there's an issue, you should explain it in your question.

Comment: Um... I did. If you have a solution you should post it as an answer.

Comment: "it seems the issue is with the component streaming system". There is nothing about this "issue" in your question or how this "issue" relates to your question: "Is there an easier way to bind the second form instance to the second data module's datasets without resorting to hand coded SomeControl.DataSource := Module2.dsSomeData for every single control".

Comment: Try reading the paragraph before the one you quoted. While others post useful answers you seem content to suggest the one thing I said I wanted to avoid and criticize me for calling you out for not reading the question very carefully.

Comment: You're criticizing the reader for not understanding instead of trying to be more clear. Fighting with auto-generated names at run-time should give some indication that you're not doing it how everyone else is doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question:
[separate dataset instances using datamodules in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760750/separate-dataset-instances-using-datamodules-in-delphi)

Basically the answer is to create your DataModule, then your Form, then set the name of the created DataModule to an empty string.  That will let the initial data binding happen but prevent other forms from seeing that Module.

In addition the next version that is created will still have the original name (no need for the numeric suffix).

Comment: Nice trick, but it will not prevent possibly lost design time settings.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Form which has data aware controls bound to DataSets in a DataModule.

That is not possible. Indirectly, ok agreed, but there has to be a necessary DataSource in between. (From the rest of your question we have to distill the information that those DataSources are on the DataModule, but the question could certainly be more transparent about that.)

> I deleted the global variable that was automatically created when the DataModule was first added to the project.

Good, stick to that custom!

> To my delight, controls in the designer could still be bound to DataSets in the DataModule without this global variable. I'm assuming the IDE is parsing the dfm of the DataModule so the designer can still "see" the DataModule.

Same incorrectness/confusion between DataSource and DataSet, but you are partly right: for the IDE being able to find a DataModule, the following must be true:

- The DataModule must be created/opened at least once during the session of the IDE (it may be closed afterwards during the session), see (*),
- The unit of that DataModule must be present in the uses list of the Form unit.

> When I create two instances of the Form and two instances of the DataModule at runtime, both instances of the Form appear to be bound to only the first DataModule that was created.

That is because you are depending on the automatic design time binding which does not work at runtime. That binding depends on the name of the DataModule. But this is not the only disadvantage of depending on design time binding, see (*).

> Inspecting the second instance of the DataModule reveals that the Name property has a number suffix that wasn't there at design time.

Plus an underscore in front of that sequential number suffix. It seems to be by design. There cannot be multiple DataModules (nor Forms) with the same name, which is comparable with Components not capable of having the same name of that of a sibling or child Component. It is a little strange though, because when giving no Owner or even different Owners, the same rule still applies for DataModules and Forms, which is unlike default TComponent behaviour. I cannot find evidence nor an explanation in the RTL/VCL code. Maybe it has something to do with all DataModules and Forms being kept in the Screen variable. We just have to accept, but it is a no-problem.

> The Form depends on a lot of DataSets in the DataModule. Is there an easier way to bind the second Form instance to the second DataModule's DataSets without resorting to hand coded `SomeControl.DataSource := Module2.dsSomeData` for every single control? ... One solution would be to move the DataSets to the Form itself.

Wherein `dsSomedata` being the DataSource!

Yes, there is an easier way. Instead of placing the DataSets on the Form, place the DataSources on the Form. Typically, a Form often has only a single or few DataSources compared to the number of data controls. That way the data control - DataSource binding remains intact (because both are read from the same DFM), and only the DataSet settings of the DataSources remain to be set manually:

```
  TCustomerForm = class(TForm)
    DataSource: TDataSource;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FData: TCustomerDataModule;
  end;

procedure TCustomerForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FData := TCustomerDataModule.Create(Self);
  DataSource.DataSet := FData.Query;
end;
```

Or, when you want to create the Form from the DataModule:

```
  TCustomerForm = class(TForm)
    DataSource: TDataSource;
  private
    FData: TCustomerDataModule;
    procedure SetData(Value: TCustomerDataModule);
  public
    property Data: TCustomerDataModule read FData write SetData;
  end;

procedure TCustomerForm.SetData(Value: TCustomerDataModule);
begin
  if FData <> Value then
  begin
    FData := Value;
    DataSource.DataSet := FData.Query;
  end;
end;
```

(*) In large projects with many Forms and DataModules, it is very common to not open every DataModule in the IDE, and (DataSource.)DataSet settings easily can get lost. Being dependent on the designtime binding by DataModule name then may result in your Forms never showing any data. This is a bug which is hard to foresee whithout checking every Form's (DataSource.)DataSet settings.

Doing it all in the above outlined manner ensures correct DataModule creation at runtime, and ensures all designtime capabilities and cleverness of the IDE providing DataSets, Fields, etc...

Comment: Yes, the data sources are, of course, between the controls and the datasets. I assumed anyone with enough knowledge to answer the question was already well familiar with the details of how data binding works.

It's a shame that after 18 years they still haven't fixed the problem with the form designer dropping links between components in different units.

Comment: Sorry for the nitpicking. I am sure you knew all about DataSources, but I found it strange that you never mention them in the question, especially where you suggest moving DataSets to the Form. I now understand that you keep DataSources with the DataSets by default. The point I tried to make is that that's not automatically the best strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I used the following solution.

My 2 instances of the form share the same `DataModule` instance. The 2 forms don't show up at the same time. I have the advantage, that the 2 forms show always the same data, since my data is in memory cached, with the `TCLientDataSet`.

e.g.

```
_dmSachkonto := TCachedDataModules.Instance.Add(TdmSachkonto) as TdmSachkonto;
```

TdmSachkonto is my DataModule.

Comment: If you have two Forms and one DataModule then cleary you dón't have the same issue! This is not an answer to the question.